# Draw on Google Maps API Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is it possible to draw over the map as it was a canvas?
Or even better, is it possible to put a transparent layer over a Google Map and dinamically paint over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any `View` on top of another `View` like here:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <fragment class="SupportMapFragment" />
  <CustomView />
</FrameLayout>
```

and override `onDraw` to paint what you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it by only coding then just create a view do drawing in its `onDraw()` method
this method was for static drawing.For dynamic drawing use `SurfaceView`.After that add `(View if static SurfaceView if dynamic)` in `oncreate()` method.as-

```
           addContentView(new View(this),new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//edit parameters according to you
```