# Google Maps Android, detect user interation in a location aware map

Tags: android, google-maps

I've an Android Application that displays a map. 
The map is by default centered on the user position following its movements (the center is updated according to the position updates).

However I want the user to be able to use gestures to navigate throw the map. When the user starts the navigation I want the "following" to stop, and a button is displayed so that it can start again.

How can I know when the user has moved the map center?
On the GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener, I don't know if the change is due to a location changed or a user interaction.
I've a a kind of working solution using the OnCameraChangeListener, but its a bit "dirty" and I don't find it very nice:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                            // gpsPosition contains the last position obtained
            if(isFollowing && gpsPosition!=null && (Math.abs(position.target.latitude - gpsPosition.latitude)>0.000001 || Math.abs(position.target.longitude - gpsPosition.longitude)>0.000001) ){
                isFollowing = false;
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

Is there a nice Solution to the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to detect user interacting with the map `OnCameraChangeListener` is surely too late to do that. It may be called seconds after user started interacting with the map.

What you need to do, is add 2 other listeners:

- `OnMyLocationButtonClickListener` - to know when to start tracking (set your `isFollowing` to `true`)
- `OnMyLocationChangeListener` - when your `isFollowing` is `true`, call `GoogleMap.animateCamera` to the new position

So the only thing left is when you set `isFollowing` to `false`:

Create an invisible overlay in your layout ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761889/draw-on-google-maps-api-android/17762095#17762095), but with normal `View` instead of custom) and assign this overlay (the `View`) an `OnTouchListener` (ok, it is 3rd, I lied that you need only 2).

In this listener always return `false`, but also set `isFollowing` to `false`. This when when user starts interacting with the map and you should stop automated camera movements.

I also see you are showing and hiding my location button, so do this where you change the value of `isFollowing`. Btw.: good idea to do that. I'll try it too.

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried this, but here are some ideas off the top of my (balding) head:

Option #1: Handle the location change updates yourself, by recentering the map yourself when the location change comes in. If a camera-change event occurs that does not appear to be tied to the location change (e.g., 5+ milliseconds later), that was presumably a user modifying the map via gestures.

Option #2: Subclass the Maps V2 `MapView` and override touch-related methods like `onTouchEvent()`. In addition to chaining to the superclass, you would know that a camera change that happens very soon from now probably is from the user modifying the map via gestures.

Option #3: Do both of the above. That way, *all* changes to the map should touch your code, which should increase the reliability of your determining the source of the camera change.

BTW, I filed [a feature request for a better solution](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6047).

Comment: A simple awnser is post on your request request: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4636#c21

Comment: @Mateu: That is Option #1 above.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way should be saving the center Longitude and Latitude of your Map.
 Now create an EventListener and check it in an if-statement:

```
if(oldLongLat != newLongLat){
//Something has moved
}else {
//Nothing has moved
}
```

Comment: How does this distinguish between changes due to location versus changes due to user actions (e.g., user panning the map)?